# why "des" does not become "de" in "il n’en donnait pas des témoignages moins éclatants"

Tags: articles

This question is on the opening paragraph of *[La Princesse de Clèves](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Princesse_de_Cl%C3%A8ves,_%C3%A9dition_Lepetit,_1820/Premi%C3%A8re_partie)* by Madame de La Fayette (édition Lepetit, 1820), or specifically *des* as highlighted.

> La magnificence et la galanterie n’ont jamais paru en France avec tant d’éclat que dans les dernières années du règne de Henri II. Ce prince était galant, bien fait, et amoureux : quoique sa passion pour Diane de Poitiers, duchesse de Valentinois, eût commencé il y avait plus de vingt ans, elle n’en était pas moins violente, et il n’en donnait pas **des** témoignages moins éclatants.

**QUESTION**

1. If I wanted to say that someone did not give signs (tokens etc.) of something, would that be as follows?

   > il n’en donnait pas **de** témoignages

   (Here I am following the rule that the plural indefinite article *des* becomes *de* when negated.)
2. If yes to 1, what accounts for *des* remaining as *des* in the quoted paragraph?  Does it for example have to do with *moins éclatants* modifying the noun?
3. If the answer to 2 is indeed modification by *moins éclatants*, what other sorts of things can come after *témoignages* (i.e. modify it) so as to force *des* to remain *des*?

Comment: Good question. Because I don't know the exact triggers for this behaviour, I won't attempt a full answer. But certainly both can be found in the wild. The more questions I see on this type of structure, the more I suspect that *pas de + [nom.]* is a marked structure interchangeable with *pas de + [det.] + [nom.]* in weaker contexts / less fixed constructions. Still cooking that thought, though, so it's probably half-baked. :p Also, are you confident that in the wider context these témoignages are not definite? (It seems unlikely that they've been referred to before, but just a thought.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence is not to be taken literally as a negation.

What is stated here is that Henri II was giving multiple striking evidences of its passion for Diane de Poitiers.

*et il n’en donnait pas des témoignages moins éclatants*

is close to:

*et il n’en donnait pas moins des témoignages éclatants*

and means:

*et il donnait des témoignages (de sa passion) aussi éclatants (que vingt ans auparavant)*

Comment: Nicely resolved!

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes
2. Yes. Another way to phrase it might have been

> les témoignages qu'il en donnait n'étaient pas moins éclatants

3. Any adjective would work. Here's another example

> Son four chauffait mal, mais ne cuisait pas des pains moins délicieux